# How to switch from a one to many relationship to a one to one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-migrations

In my rails app, I have a User who has many Companies and belongs to a Company. I would like to migrate effectively to a situation where a User has only one Company and still belongs to Company. Is it enough to change the line of code in User.rb to `has_one :company`

I have already made sure that in my database, all users have just one company. I would like to know the most effective way to complete the migration. This is my sample code for Company.rb `belongs_to :user` .
For the company create action, i have

```
  def create
    @company = Company.new(company_params)
    @company.user = current_user
    preview_company
  end
```

This is my database schema

```
  create_table "companies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "description"
    t.string "website"
    t.string "location"
    t.string "address"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.string "photo"
    t.string "logo"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_companies_on_user_id"
  end



  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean "admin", default: false, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

Comment: you will also need to change the references of `user.companies` to `user.company`

Comment: can you please explain further. You mean when I am trying to derive a company associated to a User?

Comment: You should simplify your question. "I would like to migrate effectively to a situation where a User has only one Company and still belongs to Company." is very ambiguous.

Comment: Can you provide more code?
If it is the same company then I think that relation is redundant.
If it is different companies, then you just need different association naming. E.g.
`belongs_to :company`
`has_one :owned_company, foreign_key: :owner_id, class_name: 'Company'`

Comment: What samples of code should i provide? I have added my database schema @AlexanderSysuiev

Comment: As the question about the database relation, I think it would be helpful to see current relations in the appropriate models. @HakeemBaba

Comment: BTW, in db schema I can not see how `user belongs_to company`